# does a computer virus affect all accounts on the computer?

Tags: virus

I am trying to test a game exploit software but are unsure if it has a virus,I want to try it on a seperate user account on my computer but I am unware if it will spread to other user accounts.

Comment: If this software contains malware, it will most likely compromise the entire PC (if not more: network, etc). Also, this kind of software violates most TOC for online games and rightfully results in termination of your license/account.

Comment: You are using the wrong method, don't ever run anything you don't trust on your real computer, it doesn't matter whether you are using a different account or not, and no antivirus software can ensure you are absolutely safe, instead you should run the thing inside a virtual machine, it is an emulated environment isolated from the rest of the machine, programs inside a virtual machine generally don't have any access to the real machine, in this way even if it is a virus only the expandable scapegoat VM will be down, and the real machine will be spared.

Answer (score 5):

A virus does whatever it was designed to do.

If you run it with administrative privileges (you get the security prompt when launching it), then it can theoretically do *everything it wishes* with the PC.

Otherwise it's limited to what you (your user account) can do. (including exploitation and privilege escalation - see Kamil's comment below)

The golden rule is: **Don't run anything you don't trust, ever.**

See also: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/100360/194694) (read this *before* attempting anything).

Comment: "Otherwise it's limited to what you (your user account) can do" -- This sentence is somewhat misleading if interpreted narrowly. In some circumstances "limited" is not as limited as one thinks. In general sometimes your user account is able to escalate privileges due to some bug in the OS. Bugs happen, malware likes them. So "limited to what your user account can do" may still be unsafe for the rest of the system. The golden rule says "don't *ever*" for a reason.